# java future spring Async get thread name

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a Spring @Async method and it returns Future object. I did an exception handler and some logging. When I check logs, I see error and  stack trace, though not see the thread name (just main thread name mentioned), where the exception happen. Is it possible to get thread name from Future object, to make log clear about what thread exactly happen to fail?

I see just one workaround this: Create try catch block in my @Async method and log from it. Though I thought could it be possible get thread name from Future object?

Here in my main thread I wait for task done:

```
    for (Future<SearchRequest> future:futureList){
        try {
            SearchRequest searchRequest = future.get();
            doneSearchRequests+=1;
            log.info("Progress: "+doneSearchRequests+
                    " search requests done of "+ searchRequestsNumber+ 
                    " ("+Math.round(100*doneSearchRequests/searchRequestsNumber)+"%)");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("Error while wait catalogPageService result. ",e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            log.warn("Error while wait catalogPageService result. ",e);
        }
    }
```

the **futureList** contains collection of async methods call results

Here the log record sample. The main thread name mentioned, but no info about executor thread name where this exception really happen:

```
2017-09-23 23:37:19.711  WARN 7986 --- [           main] h.service.salary.location.CatalogImpl    : Error while wait catalogPageService result.
```